# How can I create SSIS using stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, ssis, sql-server-2012

A group in my company granted me access to execute a stored procedure, and the stored procedure, if executed from excel, gives me a table. I want to store this table in SQL via SSIS.

I tried this via:
 Within DFT, I created a connection using SQL Server Native Client. And within source assissstant, I entered SQL command

```
EXEC     [dbname].[storedprocedure]
```

But then it returns an error:

```
No column information was returned by the SQL command.
```

Is there anyway to make this work?

Comment: The stored procedure returns data. Are you really asking can you use a stored procedure to create an SSIS package or is your question better phrased as "can I use a stored procedure in a package?"

Comment: What in the world are you asking sir?

Comment: Sorry I could have worded it much better. All I'm trying to do is to create a table in my SQL server based on the result I get from the procedure stored on other team's SQL server.
I only have access to executing the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Add the proper data source and then connect it to the `OLE DB Command`.  Under the Connection Manager tab, setup your connection.  Under the Component Properties Tab in the SqlCommand line enter `EXEC [Stored Procedure Name] ?` use as many `?`s for as many variables declared in your Stored Procedure.  Under the Column Mappings tab you will map your variables from the Stored Procedure to the relevant columns in your SQL Server DB.

Comment: I cannot seem to find      `OLE DB Command` in the provider list. would Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server work?

Comment: If your in SSIS, its in the SSIS Toolbox which should be on your left.  It will be under "Common".